# Error with adding a background image using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I attempt to add a background image and use cover to let the browsed resize the image. However the image is very small and doesn't cover the whole background.

I am new to angular so I have a very small idea about how this works.

Also, the search bar isn't in the middle despite using zurb to manage spacing for me.

Here is what the page looks like[image]

Here is the code:

```
<div >

    <!-- Above fold -->
    <div class="row">

        <div id = "backgroundImage" class="large-12 small-12 columns" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(img/mainBackground.png)','background-size' : 'cover'}">

            <!-- search bar -->
            <div class="row">

                <!--empty -->
                <div class="large-3 small-3 columns">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>

                <div class="large-6 small-6 columns">
                    <input type="text" id="searchBar" ng-style="{'width': '50%'}">
                </div>

                <!--empty -->
                <div class="large-3 small-3 columns">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Based on the code you've provided, styling that div via AngularJS provides absolutely no benefit. Use a stylesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding on to @Marko's response, you are using Angular to style an attribute, but the styles you are providing are just static.  Angular's `ng-style` attribute is intended to be used when you have dynamic styles that you want to apply at runtime based on a given condition.  You aren't doing that.  You're simply providing static styles that you want to be applied, inline.  That's not really considered a best practice.  It would be better to just use a static css stylesheet to do what you want.

That being said, the issue you're facing is purely a CSS one, not an angular-specific one.  You just need to debug your style on your `#backgroundImage` div and you'll eliminate a lot of the complexity involved in using `ng-style`.

Here's a good tutorial on using full-page css background images:  http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/